# MATLAB: The "dot operator" versus using a "for loop"

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, operator-keyword

I'm a bit of a beginner at matlab so I'm having a some trouble understanding differentiating a dot operator and a for loop.
Given a Column vector (it's a pretty long column vector). We are given the following equation...

> f(x)=0.2*x^3 + (1/3)*(x^2-1) + 2*cos(x)+3*cos(10x)

I need to use the method of dot operator and a for loop to create 2 plots and also the time (using tic, toc)

However, with dot operator does it mean using

> .^ or .*

in the equation? and if this is the case, wouldn't I still need to use that in order to make a for loop?
Any clarification or assistance would be greatly appreciated! I don't really understand how I would write these...

Comment: What are the two plots you want?

Comment: In a few comments you mention that your loop does not work. Please include the loop in the question if you want people to look at it otherwise they can only make guesses.

Comment: If you want to vectorize your equation in order to evaluate it element-wise for each value, then instances of `*`, `/`, and `^` where your vector is on the left and right of these operators need to be converted to `.*`, `./`, and `.^`. I strongly recommend that your read through [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) and do the example exercises. Also, the `10x` in your code is invalid and will produce an error.

Answer (score 1):

The operators prefixed with a dot are called element-wise operators. It performs the operation on each element of the arrays (after checking that all involved arrays have the same number of elements). So you don't need a for-loop with using this operator, this is implied. This is called vectorization.

For example:

```
C = A.*B;
```

is equivalent to:

```
C = zeros(size(C));
for i=1:numel(A)
    C(i) = A(i)*B(i);
end
```

but the first one is heavily optimized. So it's strongly advised to use vectorized operators as much as possible.

Comment: Okay, but for this particular case, wouldn't I have to use the dot operator in my for loop anyways? This is because when I try to write the for loop, I get an error indicating that I should use a for loop. However since I am comparing the two, I don't think I'm doing it quite correct...

Comment: If you want to plot `f(x)`, I think you only need to use `.^` and `*` (because you have only multiplications between an array and a scalar).

Comment: Oh I know that, it's just I'm trying to plot it using both the dot operator and a for loop to compare to time it takes to do both. So I was having trouble with the latter. but thank you!

Comment: Ok, now I understand. In the for-loop, since you access every element by its index, you don't need element-wise operators. Don't you forget some indexing...?

Comment: For optimal help, please edit your question with what you have done so far (and isn't working).

Answer (score 0):

your x is an vector of defined length and step size, for example it can be:

```
x = 1:1:100 %generates 1,2,3....100
x = 1:0.1:10 %generates 0.1,0.2,0.3....10
```

so if you want to write a function of x (which is a vector), for speed purposes, you might want to use the dot-product denoted by .* in matlab. In your case you can do:

```
f(x)=0.2.*x.^3 + (1/3).*(x.^2-1) + 2.*cos(x) +3.*cos(10x)
```

The more costly way to compute is to use a for loop:

```
for x = 1:100
  f(x)=0.2*x^3 + (1/3)*(x^2-1) + 2*cos(x) +3*cos(10x)
end
figure
plot(f)
```

Comment: I see, (since i'm comparing both for speed purposes) as I try to write the for loop I get an error because it says I need to use the dot operator within the for loop to even have the plot. So I'm sure there's a way where I don't have to use the dot operator? (I'm loading my x values from a txt file)

Comment: hmmm, you must have done something wrong with the loop. the structure is as follows: 1, define your x step size, for example for x =1:0.1:100 (this makes an index of 1000 in size). you now define f(x) index as f(x*10) = YOUR FUNCTION HERE, the *10 is to correctly index your f(x) since index has to be integers and cannot be 0.1, 0.2 etc. for your actual function, you use the value x each time. at the end your results will be collected in the vector f.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your for loop is that you overwrite on the value of fx2, in each iteration you give it a new value but it always remain of size 1x1. For minimal change in your code you could do something like:

```
fx2=[];

for x = A(:,4)

  fx2 = [fx2 0.2*x^3+(1/3)*(x^2-1)+2*cos(x)+3*cos(10*x)];

end

plot(x,fx2)
```

that way, you add a new value in the vector fx2 at each iteration instead of overwriting, (fx2 would be 1x1 then 1x2...). However be aware that this is not optimized at all because well there is a for loop that can be avoided but also because fx2's size changes at each iteration. Another better solution would be to predefine fx2 with the right size and then in the loop, change its ith value at the ith iteration.

Comment: well now that you edited your question and removed the code of your loop my answer doesn't make much sense..